# gRPC stream per request validation

Tags: go, nginx, grpc, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm facing an issue while using gRPC with NGINX. I have a gRPC server set as an upstream for NGINX. When a client opens a bi-directional stream, it sends a request to NGINX, which then forwards the request to the upstream server. However, I'm unsure whether it's necessary to validate each request within the stream. How can I determine if every gRPC stream request is validated?

The nginx access.log only show the rpc `stream` but not for each small request send to the stream.

```
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07T03:37:12+00:00","client":"127.0.0.1","uri":"/example.Greeter/SayHello","http-status":200,"grpc-status":0,"upstream":"127.0.0.1:50051""rx-bytes":20,"tx-bytes":127}
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07T03:37:12+00:00","client":"127.0.0.1","uri":"/example.Greeter/SayHello","http-status":200,"grpc-status":0,"upstream":"127.0.0.1:50051""rx-bytes":20,"tx-bytes":127}
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07T03:37:12+00:00","client":"127.0.0.1","uri":"/example.Greeter/SayHello","http-status":200,"grpc-status":0,"upstream":"127.0.0.1:50051""rx-bytes":20,"tx-bytes":127}
{"timestamp":"2023-12-07T03:37:16+00:00","client":"127.0.0.1","uri":"/example.Greeter/StreamHello","http-status":200,"grpc-status":,"upstream":"127.0.0.1:50051""rx-bytes":65,"tx-bytes":150}
```

But in the console

```
Response from server: Hello, Alice
Response from server: Hello, Alice
Response from server: Hello, Alice
message:"Hello, Alice"
message:"Hello, Alice"
message:"Hello, Alice"
```

In the stream, I send three Hello in row to server and server calls `send` to client like a `Ping-Pong`

What I expect is that for each request sent from client(even from stream) should have a log to record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream is an unbroken TCP stream, so you would only expect one entry.  Please see the [grpc.io conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/IqDrqMKgduY/m/VLZmBiLhAgAJ) for a detailed discussion on this.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! It's a basic concept but I just didn't understand though.